# DateTime<Utc> compiles but not DateTime<Local> querying a table with a column defined as timestamp with time zone

Tags: postgresql, datetime, rust, serde, rust-diesel

I have a postgresql-table with a column defined as `timestamp with time zone`. The table is mapped to this struct:

```rs
#[derive(Serialize, Queryable)]
pub struct Location {
    pub publication_time: DateTime<Utc>,
    pub id: i32,
    pub name: String,
    pub latitude: BigDecimal,
    pub longitude: BigDecimal,
}
```

The schema have this definition:

```rs
table! {
    locations {
        publication_time -> Timestamptz,
        id -> Integer,
        name -> Text,
        latitude -> Numeric,
        longitude -> Numeric,
    }
}
```

(partial) Cargo.toml:

```rs
serde = "1.0.125"
serde_json = "1.0.64"
serde_derive = "1.0.125"
diesel = { version = "1.4.6", features = ["postgres", "r2d2", "chrono", "numeric"] }
bigdecimal = { version = "0.1.0", features = ["serde"] }
chrono = { version = "0.4.19", features = ["serde"] }
```

The function that queries the database:

```rs
fn get_all_locations(pool: web::Data<Pool>) -> Result<Vec<Location>, diesel::result::Error> {
    let conn = pool.get().unwrap();
    let items = locations.load::<Location>(&conn)?;
    Ok(items)
}
```

This is then serialized to a JSON-array using serde_json. The DateTime in the database is `2021-04-08 15:02:02.514+02`. When DateTime is Utc the program compiles fine, but the DateTime shown in UTC like `2021-04-08T13:02:02.514Z`. I changed publication_time to `DateTime<Local>` to retain the time zone information but then `cargo build` fails with:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `DateTime<Local>: FromSql<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz, Pg>` is not satisfied
  --> src/controller.rs:21:27
   |
21 |     let items = locations.load::<Location>(&conn)?;
   |                           ^^^^ the trait `FromSql<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz, Pg>` is not implemented for `DateTime<Local>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <DateTime<Utc> as FromSql<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz, Pg>>
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::Queryable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz, Pg>` for `DateTime<Local>`
   = note: 2 redundant requirements hidden
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::Queryable<(diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz, diesel::sql_types::Integer, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Numeric, diesel::sql_types::Numeric), Pg>` for `models::Location`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `LoadQuery<_, models::Location>` for `locations::table`
```

I have another program that insert to this table and this works and the only difference is derive(Deserialize, Insertable).

```rs
#[derive(Deserialize, Insertable)]
pub struct Location {
    pub publication_time: DateTime<Local>,
    pub id: i32,
    pub name: String,
    pub latitude: BigDecimal,
    pub longitude: BigDecimal,
}
```

Comment: if I recall correctly sql doesn't have a local timestamp, it's converted to utc everytime. How would postgresql retrieve this information ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapping a `Timestamptz` field to a `DateTime<Local>` is not supported by diesel itself, as it only provides [the corresponding impl](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/pg/types/sql_types/struct.Timestamptz.html#impl-FromSql%3CTimestamptz%2C%20Pg%3E-1) for `DateTime<Utc>`.
You can work this around by using the [`#[diesel(deserialize_as = "…")]` attribute](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/deserialize/trait.Queryable.html) on the corresponding field and providing your own deserialization wrapper:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Queryable)]
pub struct Location {
    #[diesel(deserialize_as = "MyDateTimeWrapper")]
    pub publication_time: DateTime<Local>,
    pub id: i32,
    pub name: String,
    pub latitude: BigDecimal,
    pub longitude: BigDecimal,
}

pub struct MyDatetimeWrapper(DateTime<Local>);

impl Into<DateTime<Local>> for MyDatetimeWrapper {
    fn into(self) -> DateTime<Local> {
        self.0
    }
}

impl<DB, ST> Queryable<ST, DB> for MyDateTimeWrapper
where
    DB: Backend,
    DateTime<Utc>: Queryable<ST, DB>,
{
    type Row = <DateTime<Utc> as Queryable<ST, DB>>::Row;

    fn build(row: Self::Row) -> Self {
        Self(<DateTime<Utc> as Queryable<ST, DB>>::build(row).with_timezone(&Local))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I implemented it but get the error "error[E0599]: no method named `with_timezone` found for associated type `<DateTime<Utc> as diesel::Queryable<ST, DB>>::Row` in the current scope
  --> src/models.rs:43:18
   |
43 |         Self(row.with_timezone(Local))
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `<DateTime<Utc> as diesel::Queryable<ST, DB>>::Row`

Comment: @kometen I've fixed the code by added the missing conversion.

Comment: Thank you. :-) That was a delight.